# How to correctly handle multiple movement key presses resulting in double the speed?

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, physics, game-mechanics

I am trying to implement **acceleration** and **drag** into my top-down 2D game. The player can move using the WASD keys. Acceleration works fine, but the way I handle the directional velocity causes the player to abruptly stop when the movement keys are released instead of coming to a stop. Here is the code I currently have:

**EDIT:** I officially solved the above issue by implementing an **applyForce** method and triggering it when the movement keys are pressed as seen here:

```
    public void applyForce(float angle, float amount)
    {
        Vector2 v = new Vector2((float)(Math.Cos(angle)), (float)(Math.Sin(angle)));
        v.Normalize();
        v = Vector2.Multiply(v, amount);

        velocity = Vector2.Add(velocity, v);
    }

            if (oldKeys.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                applyForce((float)Math.PI, CurrentSpeed);
            }
            if (oldKeys.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                applyForce(0, CurrentSpeed);
            }
            if (oldKeys.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            {
                applyForce((float)Math.PI * 1.5f, CurrentSpeed);
            }
            if (oldKeys.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            {
                applyForce((float)Math.PI * 0.5f, CurrentSpeed);
            }
```

As you may have guessed, the new problem is that when 2 keys are pressed the method is called twice causing the player to move faster than he should be. Are there any effective ways of handling this?

Comment: Someone posted an answer and it wouldn't let me comment on it. I hope I didn't accidentally delete it because it has disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone answered the question earlier then either deleted it or I accidentally deleted it (and if so I apologize). Regardless, they pointed out that it was odd that my applyForce method was based on an angle so I fixed that, then used a modified version of their idea to fix my problem.

Here are the two new overloaded versions of **applyForce**:

```
    public void applyForce(Vector2 direction, float amount)
    {
        if (direction.Length() > 0)
            direction.Normalize();

        direction = Vector2.Multiply(direction, amount);

        velocity = Vector2.Add(velocity, direction);
    }

    public void applyForce(Vector2 v)
    {
        velocity = Vector2.Add(velocity, v);
    }
```

And the new movement key code:

```
            int x = 0, y = 0;

            if (oldKeys.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                x = -1;
            if (oldKeys.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                x = 1;
            if (oldKeys.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                y = -1;
            if (oldKeys.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                y = 1;
            if (oldKeys.IsKeyUp(Keys.A) && oldKeys.IsKeyUp(Keys.D))
                x = 0;
            if (oldKeys.IsKeyUp(Keys.W) && oldKeys.IsKeyUp(Keys.S))
                y = 0;

            Vector2 mv = new Vector2(x, y);
            applyForce(mv, CurrentSpeed);
```

Comment: Stated differently (ie. how I was about to answer): don't applyForce for every key, instead set the direction. Then after all keys call applyForce once with the set direction.

Comment: Were you the person who answered earlier then deleted the answer?

Comment: no, was just summarizing your correct answer for other newbies